# An error occurred during upgrade in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am working on react native app, started the app using CRNA command to create the project then exp detach to detach. The problem I am having is this: when I started the app I was on windows, so it only created android folder while detaching, now that I want the app to build for iOS I kinda need to generate the iOS folder, to do this I am running **react-native-git-upgrade** so that it would generate iOS folder, but it throws an error as follow:

> An error occurred during upgrade:  git-upgrade ERR! Error:
>   react-native version in "package.json"
>   (https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-26.0.0.tar.gz)
>   doesn't match the installed version in "node_modules" (0.54.2).

Is there any way that I can generate iOS folder without having to upgrade the app? I am so confused in this case and it seems that its quite benefit starting an app from an Mac OS system in this case, so u have both android and iOS folders generated.

Also tried to delete node_modules folder and tried npm install and it seems it added some packages but then again I get same problem when running **react-native-git-upgrade**

Note: I have node v10.0 installed on Mac

Anyone have any idea on this?

Comment: **First** cd node_modules, **second** rm -rf react-native, **third** react-native-git-upgrade

Comment: change `"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-26.0.0.tar.gz",` to `"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-28.0.0.tar.gz",` in your package.json, then npm install or yarn install

Comment: Neither of these suggestions work for me.

Answer (score 3):

I successfully upgrade RN project using `react-native upgrade` instead of `react-native-git-upgrade`, here's the step:

You will be need to input project name in `package.json` on project root, just add this value `"name": "<YOUR-APP-NAME>"`.

then run `react-native upgrade`, if you are prompted to downgrade RN package, to downgrade use`npm install react-native@x.x.x`, for example: `npm install react-native@0.43.4`. check installed version using `react-native -V`.

Now run `react-native upgrade`, you will be asked to replace some files, input `y` to confirm.

After the upgrade done, revert to latest version of RN package using `npm install react-native@x.x.x`.

Comment: This did not work for me. By project.json do you mean app.json?

Comment: whoops a mistake there, i was meant `package.json` thank you @luciusdegeer